# Все возможные сочетания элементов одномерного массива

Tags: php

Есть необходимость получить все возможные сочетания элементов одномерного массива.

```
$input = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

function getCombinations(array $data): array
{
    $results = array(array());
    foreach ($data as $element) {
        foreach ($results as $combination) {
            array_push($results, array_merge(array($element), $combination));
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

$combinations = getCombinations($input);
print_r($combinations);
```

Код есть в песочнице - [тут](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9296a4d6097ede1f85599fcfb869225abdf3b00b)

Однако при выполнении кода получаю ошибку о перезаполнении памяти

> Allowed memory size of ХХХХХХХХХ bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   ХХХХХХХ bytes)

Как можно задать глубину поиска комбинаций? Например, меня интересуют только парные комбинации (1+1). Можно ли как-то посчитать количество циклов, на котором нужно остановиться, зная количество элементов в исходном массиве и глубину?

Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => A
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
            [1] => A
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
            [1] => B
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
            [1] => B
            [2] => A
        )

)
```

Comment: Вы получаете все подмножества из алфавита и у вас получается массив размером 2^26. Конечно память перезаполнена. Вы хотите вывести все сочетания элементов длины 2?

Comment: @becouse 2,3,4. 5 - вряд ли. На самом деле ещё больше, т.к. у меня элементов не 26, а около 35. Алфавит для примера.

Comment: Вам их нужно сохранить или вывести на экран? Сохранить для размера больше 20 вы сможете только в файл. В лексикографическом порядке?

Comment: @becouse удобно в виде многомерного массива (как у меня в моем коде) - внтури массима подмассивы, в которых каждое значение - одно из сочетаний. Дополнил ответ. Важно понимать сочетние C-A и A-C, например, это одно и то же.

Comment: Смотрите. Если взять 17 букв, то массив в памяти занимает 15Мб. Если вы возьмете еще 9 (для английского), то получите 512*15=7680Мб, т.е. 8 гигабайт, что конечно в память не влезет. Возможно вам подойдет решение с поиском сочетаний нужной длины. Прилагаю.

Comment: @becouse так я и хочу ограничить глубину поиска (в том и вопрос). Найти все комбинации букв (буквы для примера) попарно, триплетами, квартетами и, возможно, по 5. Исходные данные (а их несколько мегабайт) имеют несколько тысяч строк. И я их спокойно считываю в массив для дальнейшей работы. Из этого массива я получаю уникальные значения определённой переменной (в данном примере это буквы). И теперь нужно найти комбинации букв.

Comment: @becouse если верить этому сайту и формуле (https://www.matburo.ru/tvart_sub.php?p=calc_C) то имея 31 элемент получим для сочетаний по 2 - 465 сочетаний, 3 - 4495, 4 - 31465, 5 - 169911. В сумме это около 210.000 сочетаний. не так уж много для массива, мне кажется... При том, что оперативки у меня 16 гигов. Если верить статье (https://habr.com/ru/post/141093/), то массив из просто чисел от 1 до 100.000 занимает 14мб.

Comment: Для 26 элементов будет 2^26 комбинаций (сумма количества комбинаций длины 1,2,3 и т.д.) Это стандартная формула комбинаторики. Вы должны понимать, что количество элементов и размер массива это разные вещи. Тогда крутите php.ini На предмет увеличения количества памяти под скрипт. Но, честно говоря, смысла в хранении всего этого в памяти я не вижу. Может быть если вы напишите задачу, которую решаете, то ситуация прояснится.

Comment: Так у вас не просто массив, а многомерный.

Comment: @becouse так у меня есть задача - получить комбинации, но все-все возможные, а только до 5 уровня максимум. А это в сумме для 31 элемента 210.000 комбинаций. Вполне себе адекватное количество. Мне нужно как-то оставить поиск комбнаций, когда я дойду до 5 уровня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот программа, которая получает все сочетания элементов массива от длины $first, до длины $last.

```
$input = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];



function getCombinations($array, $data, $start, $end, $index, &$result) {

    if ($index==sizeof($data)) {
        $s="";
        foreach ($data as $elem){
            $s=$s.$elem;
        }
        array_push($result, $s);
    }
    else{
      if ($start<=$end){
          $data[$index]=$array[$start];

          getCombinations($array,$data,$start+1,$end,$index+1,$result);
          getCombinations($array,$data,$start+1,$end,$index,$result);
      }    
    }


    }
function getCombinationsOfSize($array, $size){
 $data=array_fill(0, $size, "");
 $result=array();
 getCombinations($array,$data,0,sizeof($array)-1,0,$result);
 return $result;    
}

function getAllCombinationsRange($array,$first,$last){
 $result=array();
  for ($k=$first;$k<=$last;$k++){
     $result=array_merge($result,getCombinationsOfSize($array, $k));
  }    
 return $result;
}



print_r(getAllCombinationsRange($input,1,5));
```

Comment: прошу прощения. нет возможности сейчас посмотреть. Чуть позже.