# Как сапоставить каждый элемент массива с каждым по одному разу?

Tags: php

Есть массив вида:

```
array (
    0 => 'A',
    1 => 'B',
    2 => 'C',
    3 => 'D'
)
```

Каким образом получить из него массив вида:

```
array (
    0 => 'A-B',
    1 => 'A-C',
    2 => 'A-D',
    3 => 'B-C',
    4 => 'B-D',
    5 => 'C-D'
)
```

То есть чтобы его значения как бы сопаставились с каждым из значений по одному разу.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058330/%d0%92%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0/1058547#1058547

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом случае надо идти по номерам элементов.

```
$input = array (
    0 => 'A',
    1 => 'B',
    2 => 'C',
    3 => 'D'
);

$output=array();
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($input);$i++) {

  for ($j=$i+1;$j<sizeof($input);$j++) {

    $output[]="$input[$i]-$input[$j]";
  }
}
```

Результат

```
Array
(
    [0] => A-B
    [1] => A-C
    [2] => A-D
    [3] => B-C
    [4] => B-D
    [5] => C-D
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array (
    0 => 'A',
    1 => 'B',
    2 => 'C',
    3 => 'D'
);

$out_array = [];
foreach($array as $key=>$item){
    foreach($array as $value){
        if($item != $value){
            $out_array[] = sprintf('%s-%s',$item,$value);
        }
    }
    unset($array[$key]);
}
```

результат:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "A-B"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "A-C"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "A-D"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "B-C"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "B-D"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "C-D"
}
```